# Eloquent many-to-many relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables:

```
groups:
id, name

group_members:
id, group_id, user_id

users:
id
```

Now, what I'm looking to do, is to get all of the groups (just the groups), that have members associated with them
so, for instance i have the following:

```
groups
1, test
2, test-1
3, test-2

group_members
1, 1, 1
2, 1, 2
3, 3, 1

users
1
2
```

If I want to get all groups that user with `id = 1` belongs to, it should return:

```
groups
1, test
3, test-2
```

Is there a way in eloquent that i can just return the groups (in a collection)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence):

```
Group::whereHas('users', function($q) use($userId) {
    $q->where('id', $userId);
})->get();
```

Or:

```
User::find($userId)->groups()->get();
```

Comment: Hey can you provide the plan sql query that can achieve the same

Comment: @ThunderBird I'm trying to avoid using raw queries, but you can install Laravel Debugbar and see all raw queries generated by Eloquent there. Or by using `->toSql()` function.

Comment: select * from groups g, group_members gm
where gm.group_id = g.id
and gm.user_id = '194'
group by g.id

Answer (score 0):

```
Group::whereHas('members', function($q) use($userId) {
    $q->where('user_id', $userId);
})->get();
```

This seems to work. I had to add some of the `belongsTo` etc relationships in my models